# Reading and Printing a File With Python

Tags: python, file

I am very very new to python and will be using it to analyze data for astronomy research. To try my first code I wanted simply read and print a data table (a text file) that I already had in my directory. I continue getting a "No such file or directory" message, even when I give the direct path to the file.

```
openfile= open("//d//acadia//smartens//members","r+")
print (members.txt)
```

Also, when I try to use the file path in the print command it returns a syntax error

```
openfile= open("//d//acadia//smartens//members","r+")
print (//d//acadia//smartens//members)
```

I'm using Linux, Emacs, and SDSS & GALEX data.

I would love some suggestions and examples of simple codes like this along with explanations to why I am getting these error messages. Also when do I need to specify that is is a text file?
Thank you so much.

Comment: I strongly suggest starting out with the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/), especially the ["Reading and Writing Files"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) section when you get to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try the following code and see if it works any better:

```
import sys
with open('/d/acadia/smartens/members') as file:
    for line in file:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Also, if the following line returns `False`, then your path is not correct:

```
os.path.exists('/d/acadia/smartens/members')
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! Can  you explain why this is the correct way to do it? Why was 'import sys' required? What does 'stdout' mean? And why was 'write(line)' was used instead of a print command?

Comment: The difference between `write` and `print` is minor. `write` doesn't add a newline, which is convenient here.

Comment: There's no need to do it this way; the alternatives @noctis is showing you have some advantages, but really it's a matter of taste. Look carefully at how the filepaths were written, and read through the [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) for the answers to all your follow-up questions.